# How to reset values every day at specific time in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have scoped service ApplicationDbContext. 
In this DbContext i have user profile which holds today's user training progress

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Profile> Profile { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TrainingProgress> TrainingProgresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TrainingSchedule> TrainingSchedules { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

}
```

I want to reset Profile.TodayStepCount value in this DbContext every day at 23:59.
I can't have an instance of ApplicationDbContext in singleton service.(?)
How to run scheduled task in that case of scenario?

ALL libaries that allow you to do Task Scheduling can't do it.
I have tried Quartz.NET, FluentScheduler, Hangfire.

Comment: is this a web-based application (MVC/WebAPI etc)?  If so, this is difficult as those should ideally be stateless.  I'd change the approach - store a "Last Updated" timestamp on the profile.  When creating the context check this flag and if it's "yesterday" or earlier then reset the count & update the time.  Assuming the context is set to be "Scoped" it should be created for a new request so something like this may work.

Comment: Either use GPW's approach, or create a separate little app or service which runs as a background task to update the records. Either a Windows Service (might be overkill unless you have other jobs you need to run) or a quick console app which can be triggered by a Windows Scheduled Task or cron job.